# Possibly using if-else jquery in order to prevent additional animations

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm new to jQuery and I apologize if my problem has an obvious answer. I've researched on different ways of solving this situation but all end up with the same problem.

I have a few webpages that are linked together and use jQuery to animate menu bar on each page the same way.

The page loads with the menu bar completely visible and then scrolls down so only a portion of it is visible (I achieved this using jQuery css bottom value animation). When the user hovers over the bar, it moves back to it's original (onload) position so the contents are once again visible.

**The problem** is that I have jQuery code on document.ready to consecutively move the bar down and then upon hovering move the content up-- *so when a link is clicked and a new page is loaded, the menu bar moves up a little extra (due to the presence of the mouse over the bar on the new page as well) instead of first moving all the way down.*

I want the functionality where on every page, the bar moves down so it is partially visible and then moves back up on later interaction.

Here is the code I have been using and I would like help on breaking it down or inserting if-else logic based on the div css bottom property or something to prevent the bar from moving up first then moving all the way down (that is executing the second part of the jQuery code before the first part).

```
$('#navigation').stop().animate({bottom: '-50px'}, 1500);

$('#navigation').mouseenter(function() {
$('#wrapper').stop().delay(300).animate({bottom: '3em'}, 500);
});

$('#navigation').mouseleave(function() {
$('#wrapper').stop().delay(300).animate({bottom: '0'}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the effect I think you are describing, I would make the default style of the menu 'closed', mouseEnter(doOpen), an mouseLeave(doClose).  This way your page load code handles the closing when the user changes pages.